# How do I create a public and private key in node.js for signing data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

Using only node.js I want to achieve the following :

- Create a strong random private/public key that is human readable.
- Take a string data and the private key to create a signature in base64
- Take a string data, the public key and the signature and confirm that the signature was created by the owner of the private key.

So far I have got the following :

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var message = "This is a string I want to ensure is not tampered with.";
var sign = crypto.createSign("RSA-SHA256");
sign.update(message);
var signature = sign.sign("thisiswhereiassumetheprivatekeywillgo", "base64");

console.log(message);
console.log(signature);
```

but the console output only shows the message, the signature returns empty.

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

All modern crypto works with binary data, usually represented by bytes. Many scripting languages perform some magic conversion between bytes and characters, but the issue is that byte arrays are usually not just containing printable characters.

To convert bytes to a human readable form, you need to apply some form of [encoding](/questions/tagged/encoding). For debugging purposes it's best to convert to hexadecimals (base 16 encoding). For efficiency reasons, you could also use base 64 encoding. Both encodings are specified by [RFC4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648).